# Missing extra Cronjob in MODx Revo 2.2.0 while DitsNews 0.2.0 alpha3 depends on it?

Tags: cron, newsletter, modx

I use MODx Revo 2.2.0 and want to use DitsNews for sending newsletters. However, DitNews is depending on the extra CronJob while this extra has not been offered in the packagemanager for download anymore.

It seems to me that as of Revo 2.2.0 no cronjob or cronmanager task are available anymore. Do I miss something?

Is there another way to send newsletters with DitsNews manually instead of scheduled task?

Or is there any other extra that can send and manage newsletter within MODx?

Answer (score 0):

there is an extra for revo "CronManager" ~ I'm not familiar with it though, it's pretty new. Can you not just schedule a task in cron normally to fire your DitsNews script?

Comment: The extra CronManager is up to Revo 2.1 and I am using 2.2. This extra in not available anymore in the section for Revo 2.2.

A job in a cron of the server is not an option for me as I do want to offer my customers an option to schedule the newsletter in the backend of MODx.

Maybe a future request to the developers of DitsNews to add a function for ad-hoc sending of newsletters.

Comment: You are in shared hosting then? You might wind up having to write something yourself to jack an entry into your domains crontab... OR get yourself on twitter find/follow Modx & tweet your question - they wi retweet it to the modx community, tho I am pretty sure there are cron functions in the enterprise version ~ possibly why CronManager went missing.